# Step numbers meaning of google analytics funnels

Tags: google-analytics

Can any of you help me with this google-analytics funnel?

The steps of the funnel are as below:

The structure of my domain is very simple:

```
domain.com/brands/brand_name.html
domain.com/brands/brand_name/product_name.html
domain.com/style/style_name/product.html
```

Step1 /
Step 2 /marcas/nike.html
Step 3 /checkout/cart

52 users get on step 1.

Why 47+1+1+1+1=51 and the report says 52?
If I note / as a step of the funnel,why pages like/new-balance-574vn.html are included?

39 users get off on step 1.

Why 18+4+3+2+2=29 and the report notes 39? 
Where did the 39-29=10 users go?

6 users get on step 2.

Why did 6 users get on step 2(/marcas/nike.html)
Did these 6 users go from the pages noted to /marcas/nike.html?

The pic is here:

```
<a href="http://tinypic.com/r/2iizg41/6">Funnel view</a>
```

Can you please help?

I really appreciate your help

Kind regards

Comment: Sorry the pic is here: http://tinypic.com/r/2iizg41/6

Answer (score 0):

The boxes to the left and right are the top 5 urls and their respective entery/exit paths.  In theory, there is a 6th that is not listed (only the top 5).

39 people "exit" the funnel at step 1 and don't go to step 2. You don't have the "Required Step" checked in your goal funnel; this is letting additional people "Enter" on step 2.

Step 1: 52
Exit 1: -39
Enter 2: +6
Total Step 2: 19